# ASP.NET reading from database

Tags: asp.net

here's the problem:

I wanna make that if the value is the same that is the `TextBox2.Text` and in `Label2.Text`, I would not get redirected to the next page but instead I'd be asked to enter different text.Here's my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   con.Open();
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
   cmd.Connection = con;
   cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Question FROM Animals WHERE Question = @Question", con);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question", Label2.Text);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   if (dr.Read())
   {
      Response.Write("Enter different question");
   }
   else
   {
      if(dr[0].ToString() != TextBox2.Text)
         Session["question"] = Label2.Text;
         Session["Animal3"] = TextBox1.Text;
         Session["Question2"] = TextBox2.Text;
         Session["Animal2"] = Label3.Text;
         Session["Animal"] = Label4.Text;

         Response.Redirect("~/StartGame2.aspx");
   }
```

Comment: not clear what do you want to do.

Comment: what are `TextBox2` , `Label2` ?? , please explain more

Comment: If the data in textbox2 is equal to the label2(which is allready stored in database) it would complain about it, and ask to enter different data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CompareValidator on TextBox2

```
<asp:CompareValidator
        id="Validator1" 
        ControlToValidate="TextBox2" 
        ControlToCompare="Label2" 
        Type="String"
        Text="Enter different text." 
        runat="server" />
```

Comment: Working example ->  http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_comparevalidator

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your method with this:

```
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Question FROM Animals WHERE Question = @Question", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question", Label2.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
           if (dr[0].ToString() == TextBox2.Text)
           {
              Response.Write("Enter different question");
              return;
           }
        }

        Session["question"] = Label2.Text;
        Session["Animal3"] = TextBox1.Text;
        Session["Question2"] = TextBox2.Text;
        Session["Animal2"] = Label3.Text;
        Session["Animal"] = Label4.Text;

        Response.Redirect("~/StartGame2.aspx");

     }
```